# Pending edit bug

Tags: bug, edits

I removed an image posted as link, to post it as image.

I [sent the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17416121) without any problem and when the page loaded again, it has my edit under the name of another user and my edit was on edit requests without any change made.

[image: Screenshot of edit review. The review is still pending with one user rejecting it. The image appears on both sides with only the word 'Where' highlighted as a difference.]

---

This is the question:

[How to make an updater for my WPF application? Installing only upgraded files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366999/how-to-make-an-updater-for-my-wpf-application-installing-only-upgraded-files)

Comment: Your edit has changes, but it's not visible in the *rendered output* view. Switch to the *markdown* view and you'll see. Besides that, I guess this is simply the edit conflict resolution at work.

Comment: No, i made a different change and someone did the same

Comment: Based on the timing, it looks like they finished their edit before you made yours. They have over 2K rep so their edit didn't have to go to the review queue.

Comment: But SO's system blocks any edit if there is another one submitted

Comment: It blocks it if there's an edit pending. Since they did their's first and their edit didn't need to be reviewed (it was applied automatically) it  didn't block your suggested edit.

Comment: Nope, it blocks if someone edit while you were writing, like the owner who doesn't need to be peer reviewed!

Comment: The "edit" isn't blocked as long as you haven't submitted your suggestion, yet. It is blocked when there is a pending edit in the review queue.